# AdminLTE Bootstrap Theme Collapse Menu Not Appear

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

Need help on bootstrap theme from AdminLTE. On the picture below, left side is the original theme, then i made some modification using php include to separate the sidebar and header. I got problem on collapse function.

Problem appear on the header (not collapse) and the sidebar menu, missing.
Please advise how to fix this problem. Thank you

[image]

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

<?php include '../usersc/includes/load_css.php'?>
  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/docms/users/init.php';?>
  <?php include '../usersc/includes/topbar.php'?>
  <?php include '../usersc/includes/sidebar.php'?>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Dashboard
        <small>Control panel</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>150</h3>

              <p>New Orders</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-green">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>53<sup style="font-size: 20px">%</sup></h3>

              <p>Bounce Rate</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>44</h3>

              <p>User Registrations</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-red">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>65</h3>

              <p>Unique Visitors</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
      <!-- Main row -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Left col -->
        <section class="col-lg-7 connectedSortable">
        </section>
        <!-- /.Left col -->

        <!-- right col (We are only adding the ID to make the widgets sortable)-->
        <section class="col-lg-5 connectedSortable">
        </section>
        <!-- right col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row (main row) -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <b>Version</b> 2.4.0
    </div>
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2016 <a href="https://adminlte.io">Almsaeed Studio</a>.</strong> All rights
    reserved.
  </footer>
    <?php include '../usersc/includes/control_sidebar.php'?>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<?php include '../usersc/includes/load_js.php'?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, i put the wrong path on include

Comment: what is the include?